# Generate and set random colors on text view background within Recycler View in Android

Tags: android, random, colors, textview, android-recyclerview

I am Trying to Generate Random Colors and set the Random color as background of Text View Just Like in GMail app. The Text view is Having a circular background initially set in xml which i have done using shape. I have done some research and used some code available on internet but the changes are not reflecting in my app. 
[image: Gmail]

Below is my Recycler View Adapter Class:

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.Items> {
        ArrayList<GmailDataHolder> data;
        Context context;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<GmailDataHolder> data, Context context) {
            this.data = data;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerViewAdapter.Items onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gmail_layout_row, parent, false);
            Items i = new Items(v);
            return i;


        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.Items holder, int position) {

//Generating Random Color
            int randomAndroidColor = holder.androidColors[new Random().nextInt(holder.androidColors.length)];
            Drawable background = holder.circleTv.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
                ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(randomAndroidColor);
            } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
                ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(randomAndroidColor);
            } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(randomAndroidColor);
            }
            holder.line1.setText(data.get(position).getLine1());
            holder.line2.setText(data.get(position).getLine2() + "...");
            holder.line3.setText(data.get(position).getLine3() + "...");
            holder.time.setText(data.get(position).getTime());


            //get Star Image State from MySql DB

            MyFunctions.getStarState(data, holder, position);
    holder.circleTv.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getLine1().charAt(0)).toUpperCase());

            //Changing Star Image on Click
            MyFunctions.starClickListener(holder);


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public class Items extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView circleTv, line1, line2, line3, time;
            int[] androidColors;
            public ImageView star;

            public Items(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
//Loading Color from resources
                androidColors = itemView.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
                circleTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_circle);
                line1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_line1);
                line2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_line2);
                line3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_line3);
                time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
                star = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_star);


            }
        }
```

Colors.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#dc4538</color>
    <color name="colorFacebook">#374dae</color>
    <color name="colorCenterFb">#d5617ae6</color>
    <color name="colorStartGoogle">#d8dd4c3a</color>
    <color name="colorEndGoogle">#dd4c3a</color>
    <color name="colorEndLinkedIn">#1887b0</color>
    <color name="colorStartLinkedIn">#e31887b0</color>
    <color name="colorStrokeLinkedIn">#ec106584</color>
    <color name="colorStrokeGoogle">#b73e2e</color>
    <color name="colorStrokeFacebook">#e2263a91</color>
    <color name="status">#ba3223</color>
    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
    <item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
    <item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
    <item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
    <item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
    <item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/darkblue</item>
        <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
        <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
        <item>@color/darkorange</item>
        <item>@color/darkred</item>
    </integer-array>


</resources>
```

Initially The TextView is having the following Background declared in xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#48b3ff"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Random r = new Random();
    int red=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int green=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int blue=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;

    GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
    draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    draw.setColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
    mTextView.setBackground(draw);
```

Comment: This will set a random color every time when user will scroll.

Comment: what is the logic of adding 0 at the end? Can you explain please?

Answer (score 5):

```
//  google's material design colours from    , 254 colors
//  http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-palette

public String[] mColors = {
        "FFEBEE", "FFCDD2", "EF9A9A", "E57373", "EF5350", "F44336", "E53935",        //reds
        "D32F2F", "C62828", "B71C1C", "FF8A80", "FF5252", "FF1744", "D50000",
        "FCE4EC", "F8BBD0", "F48FB1", "F06292", "EC407A", "E91E63", "D81B60",        //pinks
        "C2185B", "AD1457", "880E4F", "FF80AB", "FF4081", "F50057", "C51162",
        "F3E5F5", "E1BEE7", "CE93D8", "BA68C8", "AB47BC", "9C27B0", "8E24AA",        //purples
        "7B1FA2", "6A1B9A", "4A148C", "EA80FC", "E040FB", "D500F9", "AA00FF",
        "EDE7F6", "D1C4E9", "B39DDB", "9575CD", "7E57C2", "673AB7", "5E35B1",        //deep purples
        "512DA8", "4527A0", "311B92", "B388FF", "7C4DFF", "651FFF", "6200EA",
        "E8EAF6", "C5CAE9", "9FA8DA", "7986CB", "5C6BC0", "3F51B5", "3949AB",        //indigo
        "303F9F", "283593", "1A237E", "8C9EFF", "536DFE", "3D5AFE", "304FFE",
        "E3F2FD", "BBDEFB", "90CAF9", "64B5F6", "42A5F5", "2196F3", "1E88E5",        //blue
        "1976D2", "1565C0", "0D47A1", "82B1FF", "448AFF", "2979FF", "2962FF",
        "E1F5FE", "B3E5FC", "81D4fA", "4fC3F7", "29B6FC", "03A9F4", "039BE5",        //light blue
        "0288D1", "0277BD", "01579B", "80D8FF", "40C4FF", "00B0FF", "0091EA",
        "E0F7FA", "B2EBF2", "80DEEA", "4DD0E1", "26C6DA", "00BCD4", "00ACC1",        //cyan
        "0097A7", "00838F", "006064", "84FFFF", "18FFFF", "00E5FF", "00B8D4",
        "E0F2F1", "B2DFDB", "80CBC4", "4DB6AC", "26A69A", "009688", "00897B",        //teal
        "00796B", "00695C", "004D40", "A7FFEB", "64FFDA", "1DE9B6", "00BFA5",
        "E8F5E9", "C8E6C9", "A5D6A7", "81C784", "66BB6A", "4CAF50", "43A047",        //green
        "388E3C", "2E7D32", "1B5E20", "B9F6CA", "69F0AE", "00E676", "00C853",
        "F1F8E9", "DCEDC8", "C5E1A5", "AED581", "9CCC65", "8BC34A", "7CB342",        //light green
        "689F38", "558B2F", "33691E", "CCFF90", "B2FF59", "76FF03", "64DD17",
        "F9FBE7", "F0F4C3", "E6EE9C", "DCE775", "D4E157", "CDDC39", "C0CA33",        //lime
        "A4B42B", "9E9D24", "827717", "F4FF81", "EEFF41", "C6FF00", "AEEA00",
        "FFFDE7", "FFF9C4", "FFF590", "FFF176", "FFEE58", "FFEB3B", "FDD835",        //yellow
        "FBC02D", "F9A825", "F57F17", "FFFF82", "FFFF00", "FFEA00", "FFD600",
        "FFF8E1", "FFECB3", "FFE082", "FFD54F", "FFCA28", "FFC107", "FFB300",        //amber
        "FFA000", "FF8F00", "FF6F00", "FFE57F", "FFD740", "FFC400", "FFAB00",
        "FFF3E0", "FFE0B2", "FFCC80", "FFB74D", "FFA726", "FF9800", "FB8C00",        //orange
        "F57C00", "EF6C00", "E65100", "FFD180", "FFAB40", "FF9100", "FF6D00",
        "FBE9A7", "FFCCBC", "FFAB91", "FF8A65", "FF7043", "FF5722", "F4511E",        //deep orange
        "E64A19", "D84315", "BF360C", "FF9E80", "FF6E40", "FF3D00", "DD2600",
        "EFEBE9", "D7CCC8", "BCAAA4", "A1887F", "8D6E63", "795548", "6D4C41",        //brown
        "5D4037", "4E342E", "3E2723",
        "FAFAFA", "F5F5F5", "EEEEEE", "E0E0E0", "BDBDBD", "9E9E9E", "757575",        //grey
        "616161", "424242", "212121",
        "ECEFF1", "CFD8DC", "B0BBC5", "90A4AE", "78909C", "607D8B", "546E7A",        //blue grey
        "455A64", "37474F", "263238"
};
```

These are the material design colors.take a random color from it.

```
// generate a random number
int i = new Random().nextInt(254);
```

it will generate a random number from 0 to 254

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        shape.setColor(Color.parseColor ("#"+mColors[new Random().nextInt(254)]));
        mTextView..setBackground(shape);
```

it will choose a random color from the list and set as textview background color

Comment: Random color i have already generated as shown in my above code but the problem rises when i set it on my text view. Since i need the color to be display in circle shape

Answer (score 4):

**This is what you want**

on BindViewHolder Method

```
 Random r = new Random();
    int red=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int green=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;
    int blue=r.nextInt(255 - 0 + 1)+0;

    GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
    draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    draw.setColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));
    holder.viewInside.setBackground(draw);
```

ps- view inside is the name of the view.

If you want the exact type of Gmail view then you can use this tiny library which will give you the exact thing you want.

https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how to make second type of view.

Comment: @BlackBlind Please explain. Its a recycler view simply.

Answer (score 3):

If you needs to use your own/required colors, just use below code

```
List<String> colors;

colors=new ArrayList<String>();

        colors.add("#5E97F6");
        colors.add("#9CCC65");
        colors.add("#FF8A65");
        colors.add("#9E9E9E");
        colors.add("#9FA8DA");
        colors.add("#90A4AE");
        colors.add("#AED581");
        colors.add("#F6BF26");
        colors.add("#FFA726");
        colors.add("#4DD0E1");
        colors.add("#BA68C8");
        colors.add("#A1887F");

// all colors used by gmail application :) may be,

 // genrating random num from 0 to 11 because you can add more or less 

Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(11- 0) + 0;

//genrating shape with colors 

GradientDrawable draw = new GradientDrawable();
        draw.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        draw.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(i1)))

// assigning to textview 
contact_name_circle.setBackground(draw); //textview
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate random (any) color you can just do
    `Color.rgb(Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255)`

If you want to pick color from your list i would sugest leaving that xml file and making the list in java of all the colors you want and then just simply using randomly picked color from that array.

Comment: I am able to generate the random color but when i set the color it is not reflecting in my app

Answer (score 1):

In your `onBindViewHolder` you can do the following:

```
int remainder = getAdapterPosition() % colorsArray.size();  
mView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorsArray.get(remainder)));
```

In this way, each RecyclerView item will show the same color on scrolling and also each time when user will see this list.