# Set the listview item with different color if image is not available

Tags: android, colors, listitem

I have one `listview` with one `imageview` and textview in each listitem.
the listview is fill with json data.
  now I want to set different color if image is not passed from `json`
like:

[image]

Comment: Make an array of colors and pick a random color each time from array.

Comment: Try [Text drawable lib](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using glide then,

`Glide.with(context).load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource,GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) { 
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                       Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),rnd.nextInt(256));   view.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    }
                });`

Answer (score 0):

check whether data loaded is null or not in your adapter.If it is null or " ",set random color to your image view.

This may help you
[Generate and set random colors on text view background within Recycler View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084162/generate-and-set-random-colors-on-text-view-background-within-recycler-view-in-a)